# Why couldn't Snoke or Kylo Ren trace Luke using the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, luke-skywalker, kylo-ren

Several times in the original trilogy, we see Force-sensitive characters recognizing someone's presence through The Force:

**A New Hope:**

- Darth Vader senses Obi-Wan before actually meeting him
- Darth Vader senses Luke (The force is strong with this one)

**Empire Strikes Back**

- Leia senses Luke hanging on the collapsing structure of Bespin

**Return of the Jedi:**

- Darth Vader (and the Emperor) sense Luke Skywalker on the ship, then on the planet, and the other way round.

Why then, in *The Force Awakens*, Kylo Ren and Snoke have to hunt for Luke's coordinates, instead of locating him through the Force? Both of them seem quite capable with Force techniques.

Comment: Sheer distance?  All your examples take place at a planetary scale.  Lack of directionality?  Nearby Dark Side locations?  Like how Yoda was using the emanations from the tree to hide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Luke has "cut himself off from the Force". This apparently makes him invisible to other Force users like Rey, Kylo Ren and Snoke.

> “I saw everything,” she said. “The island, and past it I felt the stars singing. I thought my heart would explode. **But I didn’t see you. Nothing from you. No light, no dark. You’ve closed yourself off from the Force.”**
>   Luke stared at her, his face pale and drawn.
>   “I’ve seen this raw strength only once before, in Ben Solo,” he said. “It didn’t scare me enough then. It does now.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Last Jedi: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

The fact that he's living slap bang on top of an ancient Jedi Temple (complete with emanations of *light and dark* Force energy) probably isn't helping matters either.

You may wish to note that this is a trick that Luke's mentor Yoda used to great effect, living on a planet with lots of vegetation, next to a cave steeped in dark Force energy, cloaking his presence from the Emperor. Luke would certainly have been aware of this ruse.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer per se but a follow-up to Valorum's:

The First Order & Snoke had no real way to know where Luke had even started, and the Galaxy is a *very* big place. Consider this:

In ANH, Vader senses Obi-Wan while on the Death Star (within a ~80-km radius) and Luke when he's much closer during the Trench Run.

In ESB, Leia sensed Luke from several kilometers away on Bespin but they were still on the same planet and he was specifically reaching out with the Force to call to her; ditto with Luke and Vader on the *Falcon* and *Executor* just after that (relatively short distances).

In RotJ, *Tydirium* was flying quite close to *Executor* and again, they were still within a radius of mere kilometers on the surface. Leia felt Luke survived the Death Star's explosion, but that was still a relatively short distance from the planetbound shuttle to the surface.

It seems to me as though there's still some element of distance/proximity *and* concentration required to really be able to sense or track someone through the Force. Otherwise, why send Luke to live on Tatooine if he could be sensed from across the Galaxy? And, for that matter, why didn't Vader sense Obi-Wan or his son while in orbit over Tatooine to begin with?

Now, yes, Obi-Wan was able to feel the The Disaster from the *Falcon* while en-route to Alderaan but that was an entire planet's worth of terror and death, and yes, Yoda could feel Order 66 from Kashyyyk but he was one of the most powerful Force-users in the galaxy and, again, it was hundreds of deaths (of Force Sensitives, no less) in a matter of moments. So in those cases, it makes sense that someone trained in the Force would be able to feel it without intending to.